# Can I have a global mixin and a imported one on Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

so,  I have this Vue 2 project with a global mixin:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from "@/plugins/vuetify"; // path to vuetify export
import VueLayers from "vuelayers";

require("./assets/css/style.css");
import "vuelayers/lib/style.css"; // needs css-loader

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueLayers);

Vue.mixin({
  data() {
    return {
      placeholderOptions: [
        {
          item: "ex1",
          valor: 0
        },
        {
          item: "ex2",
          valor: 1
        }
      ]
    };
  
  }
});

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  store: store,
  vuetify,
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

AND I have a folder with other mixins separated by file, that I can import on my components if I want. Example of mixin of this folder:

```js
import parametros from "../mockup/parametros.json";
export default {
    data() {
    },
    methods: {
        getOptions(parametro) {
            let options = [];
            parametros[parametro].forEach((item, i) => {
                options.push({
                    item: (i + 1) + " - " + item.nome,
                    value: i + 1
                })
            })
            return options
        }
    }
}
```

But when I import this mixin on my component, It's like all the components in the app cannot see the global mixin anymore. I can't use more than one mixin, if one of them is a global one? Or am I doing something wrong? Here is a example of importing the mixin of my mixin's folder, having the global one.

```html
<script>
import parametrosMixin from "../../../mixins/parametrosMixin.js";

export default {
  name: "AtributosGerais",

  mixins: [parametrosMixin],

 ...etc
};
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce this ~ https://jsfiddle.net/1hzwf86j/. As you can see, the global mixin data is correctly merged with the component mixin

Comment: Thank you for reproduce the problem, I should have done that. The problem was on the data() function on mixing returning nothing

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out the problem, I was declaring a data() on my mixin that was returning nothing, as you can see on the question :(